# How to have the twitter "show more" effect but without ajax?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have an unordered list of 50 items. I want to show only 10 at a time with a More link at the bottom. [Exactly like this](http://youhack.me/demo/pagination%20alternative/twitter%20style/twitter_style_pagination.php) only without ajax as I don't need it.

Could you please give me a tip or direct me to a tutorial on how I can achieve this effect?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** Thanks Royi Namir for [the link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination). I'm trying to show 2 items per page from a list of 10 but can't figure what I'm doing wrong...

**JS**

```
function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
                // Get number of elements per pagionation page from form
                var items_per_page = 2;
                var max_elem = Math.min((page_index+1) * items_per_page, members.length);
                var newcontent = '';

                // Iterate through a selection of the content and build an HTML string
                for(var i=page_index*items_per_page;i<max_elem;i++)
                {
                                      newcontent = jQuery('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+i+')').append();
                }

                // Replace old content with new content
                $('#Searchresult').html(newcontent);

                // Prevent click eventpropagation
                return false;
}

/** 
 * Initialisation function for pagination
 */
function initPagination() {
        // Create content inside pagination element
        $("#Pagination").pagination(10, {
                callback: pageselectCallback,
                load_first_page:true,
                items_per_page:2 
        });
 }

// When document is ready, initialize pagination
$(document).ready(function(){      
        initPagination();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Pagination"></div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
    <div id="Searchresult">
        This content will be replaced when pagination inits.
    </div>

    <!-- Container element for all the Elements that are to be paginated -->
    <div id="hiddenresult" style="display:none;">
        <div class="result">111</div>
        <div class="result">222</div>
        <div class="result">333</div>
        <div class="result">444</div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT #2:** Found my answer :D http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

demo is here :

http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm

Comment: Thank you! This is actually better than what I wanted. However, I'm having a bit of problem writing the callback function...

Comment: first choose the answer which helped you. and then open a new question :)

Answer (score 2):

Load the complete content if you don't want to use AJAX.

You can hide elements with jQuery and CSS. Take for example a look at `show()` and `hide()`.
You can toggle this on click on your *show more* link and replace this link with a *show less* link instead, too.

http://api.jquery.com/show/
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Of course the hide-link was an addition by me. You hide the _old_ more button or position it at the bottom and replace the target/selector to the next element to show.

Answer (score 1):

The very simplest way I can think of doing this is via a few hide show links.

add this simple code to the bottom of your page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
        // choose text for the show/hide link - can contain HTML (e.g. an image)
        var showText = 'expand';
        var hideText = 'hide';

        // initialise the visibility check
        var is_visible = false;

        // append show/hide links to the element directly preceding the element with a class of "toggle"
        $('.toggle').prev().append(' <a href="#" class="toggleLink">' + showText + '</a>');

        // hide all of the elements with a class of 'toggle'
        $('.toggle').hide();

        // capture clicks on the toggle links
        $('a.toggleLink').click(function () {

            // change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
            if ($(this).html() == hideText) {
                $(this).html(showText);
                $(this).removeClass('hide');
                $(this).parent().removeClass('purple');
            }
            else {
                $(this).html(hideText);
                $(this).addClass('hide');
                $(this).parent("h2").hide();
            }

            // toggle the display - uncomment the next line for a basic "accordion" style
            $(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle();

            // return false so any link destination is not followed
            return false;

        });
    });
</script>
```

then just wrap each group of ten items like

```
<div class="nextresults">
        <h2 class="more">Show More</h2>
         <div class="toggle">
           {10 results go hear!!}    
         </div>
  </div>
```

For a full expiation of this code goto http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/jquery-show-hide-multiple-elements/